# PHP use class variable in a class array

Tags: php, arrays, class, variables

I am trying to use a variable in an array within my class

```
class MyClass {

public static $a = "World";

public static $b = array("Hello" => self::$a);

}
```

This code doesn't work. Should I be using `MyClass::$a` or something else. Any ideas?

Comment: Class properties can't contain expressions that have to be evaluated at runtime, and `self::$a` requires a runtime evaluation. If your $a isn't going to change, make it a constant

Comment: Initialize `$b` in the class constructor.

Comment: @Barmar, slightly awkward to initialize in the constructor as it's `static`

Comment: Only slightly. `if (!$b) { self::$b = array(...) }`.

Comment: @Barmar - but that means instantiating the class, which shouldn't be a prerequisite for anything defined as static

Comment: I believe, that this class would never use a `constructor`. Would it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably can instatiate them at runtime:

```
class MyClass {
    public static $a;
    public static $b;
}

MyClass::$a = "World";
MyClass::$b = [ "Hello" => MyClass::$a ];
```

Or you can create a static initialization method:

```
class MyClass {
    public static $a;
    public static $b;

    public static function init(){
        static::$a = "World";
        static::$b = [ "Hello" => static::$a ];
    }
}

MyClass::init();
```

Comment: This is very good. It works on what @awlad-liton said, but this approach is more useful - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

If your $a won't change, make it a constant

```
class MyClass {

    const a = "World";

    public static $b = array("Hello" => self::a);

}

var_dump(MyClass::$b);
```

Comment: Yes, this does work. However in the context I want to use it, I don't want $a to be a constant.

Comment: In that case, if your properties still need to be static, @HAL9000 has provided your options.

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass {

    public static $a = "World";
    public static $b;
    public function __construct(){
      self::$b = array("Hello" => self::$a);
    }

}
$obj = new MyClass();
```

Comment: Yes I think that's the answer. I have to use a `__construct` function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that if you want $b to automatically reflect any changes made to $a, you'll need to set self::$a by reference

Comment: @Jason Lipo: You accepted my answer and after that someone edited his answer after acceptance you did change your acceptance also!!

Comment: I changed the acceptance not because of the edit. I tried the static function approach from @HAL9000 and that proved to work the most simply.